# Prevent access to specific directory path

Tags: php, .htaccess

In my application is possible to create a directory, and the user can store files inside that folders. So suppose that I have the following structure:

```
/public_html
    /app
        /assets 
            /documents
                /folder_name 
                -list of files
```

My goal is to prevent that the user types as URL:

```
https://myapp.com/assets/documents
```

or

```
https://myapp.com/assets/documents/folder_name
```

and see all the files or directories available in there, is there a way to prevent this via .htaccess?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Do you only want to avoid that anybode uses the directory listing, or do you want to block the whole access to that directory and all containing files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to simply prevent the directory listing, you can put:

`Options -Indexes`

inside an `.htaccess` file in the root directory of your assets. Your vhost/server configuration must have the `AllowOverride Options` set for this to work though.

If you wish to prevent the files from being accessed you could use the `<Files` directory which is allowed inside an `.htaccess` file, but the better solution would be to simply move that directory out of the public root.

Answer (score 2):

Put .htaccess in that folder, and add

`Deny from all` within

Or if you want to apply the directive dynamically to folder (in case you have access to Apache configuration):

```
<DirectoryMatch "^/public_html/app/assets/documents/(.+)/" >
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</DirectoryMatch>
```

or within the folder_name:

```
<DirectoryMatch "^/public_html/app/assets/documents/folder_name(.+)/" >
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</DirectoryMatch>
```

One of the approaches is to generate blank index.php within a folder.

Comment: the problem's that the folder is created automatically, so I would like to know if is possible to this in the main .htaccess of the application which is located in side the folder `app`

Comment: The `Directory` / `DirectoryMatch` directive can only appear in the vhost/server configuration. It cannot be set in an `.htaccess` file - [per documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directorymatch). Your answer is invalid.

Comment: Infact I tried and doesn't work, I guess the only solution is create the .htaccess automatically when the folder is created, right?

Comment: @sfarzoso, you could also create a blank index.php in that directory dynamically